# element on hover at preview image of fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I need to merge 2 classes, but one is overlaping another. I used to have `thumbLink` that is a lupe image that links to the image itself, and i can't make it work with the `fancybox-thumbs` because if i use the `thumblink`, there is no fancybox gallery, and if i use `fancybox-thumbs` there is no lupe, and the `link` to the large image is the thumbnail itself!!!! i already tried using both `<a class= thumbLink fancybox-thumbs .....</a>` but it doesn't work! now i messed up my entire gallery trying to make it work! 
Please, check my gallery when i used prettyphoto> www.nausea.ws

And now see what's going on right now:

```js
 /*!
 * Thumbnail helper for fancyBox
 * version: 1.0.7 (Mon, 01 Oct 2012)
 * @requires fancyBox v2.0 or later
 *
 * Usage:
 *     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
 *         helpers : {
 *             thumbs: {
 *                 width  : 50,
 *                 height : 50
 *             }
 *         }
 *     });
 *
 */
(function ($) {
 //Shortcut for fancyBox object
 var F = $.fancybox;

 //Add helper object
 F.helpers.thumbs = {
  defaults : {
   width    : 50,       // thumbnail width
   height   : 50,       // thumbnail height
   position : 'bottom', // 'top' or 'bottom'
   source   : function ( item ) {  // function to obtain the URL of the thumbnail image
    var href;

    if (item.element) {
     href = $(item.element).find('img').attr('src');
    }

    if (!href && item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
     href = item.href;
    }

    return href;
   }
  },

  wrap  : null,
  list  : null,
  width : 0,

  init: function (opts, obj) {
   var that = this,
    list,
    thumbWidth  = opts.width,
    thumbHeight = opts.height,
    thumbSource = opts.source;

   //Build list structure
   list = '';

   for (var n = 0; n < obj.group.length; n++) {
    list += '<li><a style="width:' + thumbWidth + 'px;height:' + thumbHeight + 'px;" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.jumpto(' + n + ');"></a></li>';
   }

   this.wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-thumbs"></div>').addClass(opts.position).appendTo('body');
   this.list = $('<ul>' + list + '</ul>').appendTo(this.wrap);

   //Load each thumbnail
   $.each(obj.group, function (i) {
    var href = thumbSource( obj.group[ i ] );

    if (!href) {
     return;
    }

    $("<img />").load(function () {
     var width  = this.width,
      height = this.height,
      widthRatio, heightRatio, parent;

     if (!that.list || !width || !height) {
      return;
     }

     //Calculate thumbnail width/height and center it
     widthRatio  = width / thumbWidth;
     heightRatio = height / thumbHeight;

     parent = that.list.children().eq(i).find('a');

     if (widthRatio >= 1 && heightRatio >= 1) {
      if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
       width  = Math.floor(width / heightRatio);
       height = thumbHeight;

      } else {
       width  = thumbWidth;
       height = Math.floor(height / widthRatio);
      }
     }

     $(this).css({
      width  : width,
      height : height,
      top    : Math.floor(thumbHeight / 2 - height / 2),
      left   : Math.floor(thumbWidth / 2 - width / 2)
     });

     parent.width(thumbWidth).height(thumbHeight);

     $(this).hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn(300);

    }).attr('src', href);
   });

   //Set initial width
   this.width = this.list.children().eq(0).outerWidth(true);

   this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5)));
  },

  beforeLoad: function (opts, obj) {
   //Remove self if gallery do not have at least two items
   if (obj.group.length < 2) {
    obj.helpers.thumbs = false;

    return;
   }

   //Increase bottom margin to give space for thumbs
   obj.margin[ opts.position === 'top' ? 0 : 2 ] += ((opts.height) + 15);
  },

  afterShow: function (opts, obj) {
   //Check if exists and create or update list
   if (this.list) {
    this.onUpdate(opts, obj);

   } else {
    this.init(opts, obj);
   }

   //Set active element
   this.list.children().removeClass('active').eq(obj.index).addClass('active');
  },

  //Center list
  onUpdate: function (opts, obj) {
   if (this.list) {
    this.list.stop(true).animate({
     'left': Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5))
    }, 150);
   }
  },

  beforeClose: function () {
   if (this.wrap) {
    this.wrap.remove();
   }

   this.wrap  = null;
   this.list  = null;
   this.width = 0;
  }
 }

}(jQuery));
```

```css
#fancybox-thumbs {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 8050;
 
}

#fancybox-thumbs.bottom {
 bottom: 2px;
}

#fancybox-thumbs.top {
 top: 2px;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul li {
 float: left;
 padding: 1px;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul li.active {
 opacity: 0.75;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul li:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: none;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul li img {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: none;
}
}
#folio {
 background: url(../images/gallery-quote.png) center 80px no-repeat #111;
 padding-top: 100px;
 clear: left;
}
.portfolio_container {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box figure a img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box .hover_effect {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.gallerySelector {
 background: #222;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.gallerySelectorList {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.gallerySelectorList li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
}
.gallerySelectorList li:hover {
 background: #83103e;
}
.gallerySelectorList li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 11px 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0;
 transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
.gallerySelectorList li.current {
 background: #7b133c;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
 width: 20%;
}
.fullwidth {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}
#gallery h3 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.project-title {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 7px;
}
.project-description {
 color: #868991;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.columns .overlay-content.loupe {
 width: 34px;
 height: 34px;
 background: url(../../../templates/images/loupe.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 top: 22%;
 margin: -17px 0 0 -17px;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 10;
}
.thumbLink {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.fechar {
 text-align:right;
 margin-left:95%;
 font-size:11px; 
}
.thumbImage {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.thumbImage img {
 transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText h3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText p {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 width:280px;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57); 
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 
}
.ie8 .thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 display: none;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: -0.5em;
}
.thumbText {
 text-align: center;
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 280px;
 
}
.thumbImage:hover img {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1.5);
 
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 opacity: 1;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 display: block;
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbText {
 transform: scale(1);
}
.thumbLink {
 background: url(../images/icons/icon-magnify.png) center center no-repeat #fff;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbLink:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.portfolioBottom {
 background: #111111;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 clear: left;
}
.isotope-item {
 z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 1;
}
.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 transition: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="folio" class="page section">
        
     
        <div class="gallerySelector">
            <ul class="gallerySelectorList">
                <li class='current'><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='principal']" href="#">Principal</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='redacao']" href="#">Redação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='criacao']" href="#">Redação-Criação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='social']" href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='video']" href="#">Audiovisual</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
        <section class="portfolio_container">
            
   <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/pt-rec1.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle" style="
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-right: 65px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
">Portifólio #</h3>

                            <a class="thumbLink fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/prec1.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/pt-rec1.jpg"data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>

            <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                 <img src="images/gallery/pt-rec2.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle" style="
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-right: 65px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
">Portifólio #</h3>
                            <a class="thumbLink fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/prec2.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/pt-rec2.jpg"data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article> 
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle" style="
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-right: 65px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
">Portifólio #</h3>
                            <a class="thumblink fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/rec3.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."><img src="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/pt-rec4.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle" style="
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-right: 65px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
">Portifólio #</h3>
                            <a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/prec4.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/pt-rec4.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" ><img src="images/gallery/pt-rec4.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
```

Comment: Are you modifying the original fancyBox thumbnail helper? (you shouldn't) if not, you don't need to include that code but your custom fancybox script initialization code

Comment: @JFK hello again! i searched all around the web for answers and i think you know everything about fancybox! Look, these are the original files i downloaded from the website. All i need is to make the lupe image link to the fancybox image. (just like pretty photo used to do here www.nausea.ws)

Comment: This task seems impossible for someone who isn't programmer and just want a cute personal website.

It is better stick to prettyphoto then.